# Scheduling a Spark Job from a NodeJS or Play! Server

Tags: node.js, scala, playframework, apache-spark

I need to be able to schedule a spark job from a Server outside of the Spark cluster programatically. If this is possible from a NodeJS server that is preferred, but it seems more doable from a Play! server using Scala. I have a spark Job that compiles and runs successfully using spark-submit on the machine for Spark itself, but I would like that to be activated from another machine.

I found documentation here for this Spark Launcher: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkLauncher but this still seems to only be useable from the Spark machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've found since I've asked this is that Spark apparently has a hidden REST API. Why this is hidden and there is no official documentation for it I'm not sure, it may be possibly used internally for testing. Anyways this article does a pretty good job explaining how to use it and I was able to call Spark from my NodeJS server using this.

http://arturmkrtchyan.com/apache-spark-hidden-rest-api

Below is an example of a curl request to submit an application request from the article:

```
    curl -X POST http://spark-cluster-ip:6066/v1/submissions/create --header "Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8" --data '{
      "action" : "CreateSubmissionRequest",
      "appArgs" : [ "myAppArgument1" ],
      "appResource" : "file:/myfilepath/spark-job-1.0.jar",
      "clientSparkVersion" : "1.5.0",
      "environmentVariables" : {
        "SPARK_ENV_LOADED" : "1"
      },
      "mainClass" : "com.mycompany.MyJob",
      "sparkProperties" : {
        "spark.jars" : "file:/myfilepath/spark-job-1.0.jar",
        "spark.driver.supervise" : "false",
        "spark.app.name" : "MyJob",
        "spark.eventLog.enabled": "true",
        "spark.submit.deployMode" : "cluster",
        "spark.master" : "spark://spark-cluster-ip:6066"
      }
    }'
```